# Graphql Schema update rollback

Tags: scala, graphql, apollo, sangria

We are moving some of our API's to graphql and would like to know to handle the rollback of the deployed package (Schema)and  the best practice to the same.

To be more specific let's say we have a Schema S with 3 fields and then we added 4th field "A" . Now for some reason we cannot go forward with this package and field "A". So we have to perform roll back of the package so that now the Schema doesn't have field "A".

Now some consumer might ask for this field "A" and he might get an error. We could of course ask our clients to update but there is a time gap during which we might have failed request.

How do we handle this scenario,specifically an urgent rollback with in few hours or a day?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should avoid removing fields without warning to avoid the exact scenario you describe.

As your schema evolves, it's not uncommon to have some fields that are no longer needed. For example, rather than introducing a drastic change to a particular field (moving from a nullable to a non-nullable return type, adding required arguments, etc.), we may opt to add another field and encourage clients to transition to using that one instead. In such scenarios, we want to eventually remove the original field. The safest way to do so is to deprecate the field first. Using SDL, we can do so using a directive:

```
fieldA: String @deprecated(reason: "Use fieldB instead!")
```

After a certain amount of time, you can then remove the field entirely. How long you wait to remove the field depends on your team and the expectations you've communicated around handling deprecated fields. For example, you may find it helpful to set a deadline, by which point all clients are expected to have stopped using any deprecated fields. This works well as long as your client teams have the bandwidth to handle such technical debt.

A deprecated field's resolver can be changed to return a null value (if the field itself is nullable) or some minimal mock data. This prevents making unnecessary API or database calls, while still ensuring client requests don't result in an error.

In the context of your question, this means you should probably avoid rolling back to a previous release and instead follow the process outlined above for the fields you want to remove.

Alternatively, you could consider versioning. GraphQL generally shies away from the concept of versioning. As the official site explains:

> Why do most APIs version? When there's limited control over the data that's returned from an API endpoint, any change can be considered a breaking change, and breaking changes require a new version. If adding new features to an API requires a new version, then a tradeoff emerges between releasing often and having many incremental versions versus the understandability and maintainability of the API.
>
> In contrast, GraphQL only returns the data that's explicitly requested, so new capabilities can be added via new types and new fields on those types without creating a breaking change. This has led to a common practice of always avoiding breaking changes and serving a versionless API.

With that in mind, it's also feasible to still implement versioning with GraphQL by serving different schemas from different endpoints. While it's costly and usually unnecessary to go that route, it may be the right solution for you and your team, particularly if you expect to have to do similar rollbacks in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have gone through the best practices for deprecating fields and your answer also give good information but I'm more concern about some emergency roll backs. Let's say we deployed and within few hours we realize things have gone haywire and now we rollback. With rest we simply ignore the requested fields not there in the request model,may not be the best way but still keeps our API and business running. In case of Graphql we will end up with fail  responses which will be a nightmare for business continuity.

Comment: Even with REST, you can potentially encounter the same issues. For example, adding query parameters to an endpoint and then doing a rollback will also result in client requests blowing up if you have request validation set up.

Comment: If you have a development and/or staging environment set up, integration testing should uncover any major issues. Speaking from experience, when we had something go horribly wrong on the backend, it was almost always uncovered in the development environment, as client teams began to integrate the schema changes into their apps. If any bugs got through to production, they were fairly low impact and certainly did not warrant rolling back to an earlier release.

Comment: I share that because if you're having to do rollbacks in production, that may be highlighting some deficiencies in your entire development/QA workflow.

Comment: Ya I was wondering about this claim of not having versions either. Deprecation is a good method but still doesn't change the fact if you have older clients and want to update or remove something. My definition of version-less would have to include older and newer clients, I just don't see how that is possible without being extra careful of changes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything w.r.t GraphQL. Since you need to have the field present in the GraphQL type system. There may be libraries available, which will allow you to specify whether the field **should** be present in the query or not. But, there's no way of allowing non-existent field in the Query.

But what you can do is opt for a **Blue-Green** deployment strategy. In this strategy, you have both the versions running at the same time.

Let's say: **Green** is the version **with Field A** and **Blue** is the version **without Field A**. So when your clients are updated they start requesting the **Blue** version. And once all your clients are updated, shut-down the **Green (*with Field A*)**.